# Is it possible to check whether a checkbox has been ticked within it's value?

Tags: php, html

To save me making masses of edits to the rest of my code I want to make a checkbox act like a textbox.

I have the following textbox, that if a number is greater than 0 then it adds items to a basket.

```
<input type="textbox"
       value="<? echo $item[qty]; ?>" 
       name="<? echo $productid."_".$product_quantity[id]."_".$product_option[id]; ?>" 
/>
```

How can I make a checkbox act the same way? I.e If it's ticked it's value equals 1, therefore adding it to my basket. If it remains unticked then it's value equals 0, therefore ignored.

```
<input type="checkbox"
       value="<? echo $item[qty]; ?>"
       name="<? echo $productid."_".$product_quantity[id]."_".$product_option[id]; ?>"
/>
```

I have several of these checkboxes going down the page.

Comment: on which event you want to check this?

Comment: @Astha Just updated question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... do you want to output 1 when $item['qty'] equals true? In that case: <input type="checkbox"<?php echo $item['qty'] ? ' value="1"' : '' ?> etc etc />

Comment: please see the edit in my answer.

Comment: @Rob Setting the value to 0 if it is not checked serves no purpose - at least not when the form is submitted; a non-checked checkbox simply does not get submitted so it's value does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the value from `value="<? echo $item[qty]; ?>"` to `value="1"`

In the action of you form i.e. wishlist.php :

```
if(isset($_POST["name_of_checkbox"])) {
   //It means check box has been ticked
   $myvalue = 1;
} else {
   //It means check box was not ticked
   $myvalue = 0;
}
```

HTH

---

This is another approach to the question maybe this is what you need.

I would introduce a hidden field which will store/post the 0 or 1 value. We will bind an event with the checkbox that will update the value of the hidden input.

```
<input name="my_cb" id="my_cb" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="my_cb_hidden" id="my_cb_hidden" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#my_cb").click(function() { 
    if($("#my_cb").is(":checked")){
         $("#my_cb_hidden").val($(this).val());  
    } else {
         $("#my_cb_hidden").val(0);    
    } 
    alert($("#my_cb_hidden").val());    
});
```

Comment: Just updated my question to make it more clear, see the update bit

Comment: Doing it via php is not possible since php is rendered server side and the user cannot tick or not tick the check box at that stage. The other option I can suggest is changing the value using javascript.

Comment: Doesn't really matter how it's done as long as it works like my example provided.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the value of checkbox value from

```
value="<? echo $item[qty]; ?>"
```

to

```
value="1"
```

then if it is checked then on Submit it will automatically store 1 as a value

***EDITED :***

after submitting in php code do it as as you updated your question

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox name']))
{
    $item[qty] = 1;
}
else
{
    $item[qty] = 0;
}
```

but this will only make the changes in the $item array's value inspite of the value your checkbox hold.

Comment: But that will mean it's always 1 whether it's ticked or not. I want it to show 1 if ticked and 0 if not ticked.

Comment: see if its the only check box with this name then on submit of the form if its ticked then only you will get it on $_POST or on $_GET otherwise if its not checked then you will not get any value from this name then you can manually assign 0 because then it means that its not checked.

Comment: Just updated my question to make it more clear, see the update bit.